# Steps to test Cordova Hybrid Mobile Application using Appium

Tags: cordova, unit-testing, appium, hybrid-mobile-app, appium-ios

I am looking to test my Hybrid Mobile Application build using JQuery Mobile wrapped with Cordova. I want to use Appium to  automate my tests.

Using Node, I installed Appium. The documentation for Native Android and IOS Applications are good but I didn't find any guide which describes the steps to work with Hybrid Mobile Application with Cordova.

Can anyone suggest or give me the steps to write tests to automate the UI which runs in Emulator or Device. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Cordova test can be used for UI automation. Check out the link below
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-test

Comment: Did the answer helped?

Comment: I was trying to get the framework which you suggested working these many hours but couldn't do. I followed the steps given and when I ran the test under the root folder of my Cordova Application, It gives me error like "Cannot find module '../dist/CDVAutomator.js' ". Can you please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Looks like it was a known issue https://github.com/Urucas/cordova-test/issues/16 . Is that fixed and new build got released ?

Comment: I am not checked that in recent times